# find the number of comparisons in the execution of the loop for any n>0 in the given code

Tags: c

Consider the following `C` code

```
int j,n; //declaration
j=1; //initialization
while(j<=n)  //while loop
   j=j*2;  //code ends here
```

What is the number of comparisons made in the execution of the loop in the above code?

I have tried the following: let increment of `j` is `pow(2,0)`, `pow(2,1)`, `pow(2,2)`, etc. For some value of `i` so according to the question

```
pow(2,i)<=n
i<=(log n/log2)
```

What after this? The answer is `floor(log n/log 2)+1` but how?

Comment: Do you want to calculate how many loops there will be depending on `j` and `n`?

Answer (score 1):

That code is undefined, there is no answer since you don't specify the value of `n` and as the code is written there's no chance for `n` to *have* a well-defined value when the loop runs.

Comment: That's true but I don't think he was concerning about the code... In my opinion the relevant question was... why are `floor(log n/log 2)+1` the number of step required for a given `n`?

Answer (score 1):

`n` is never initialised, so technically the behaviour is *undefined* as you're using an uninitialised variable in `while (j<=n)`.

If you want to set `n` to the largest possible integer value, use

`n = INT_MAX`

Which is defined in the standard include file `<limits.h>`

**But**, that will result in integer overflow due to `j=j*2` happening after the `j<=n` check. One way round this would be to define `n = INT_MAX / 2`. Better still use a `do / while` loop rather than `while` and perform the check at the end.

Comment: I think he just wants to calculate before hand how often the loop will run, depending on the 'to be filled in' value `n`. In that case his code is just a small snippet and the value of `n` is important.

Comment: @DaanTimmer Yes I think you're more likely to win in a game of *guess the spec* than me in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you initialized the variable `n` with a proper value, as you know you are going to `pow(2,i)<=n` which means `i<=log{2}n` (just inverting the function).
`log{base 2}n = log n/log2` for the well known logarithmic property. 
Now the calculation is exact when `i` is real but in this case `i` is an integer you won't get exactly that number so the correct index will be in the approximation of `[floor(logn/log2);floor(logn/log2)+1]` which will be the loop required for for `pow(2,i)<=n<pow(2,i+1)`

Let's do a simple example:

```
n=11; ln(n)/ln(2)=2.39/0.69=3.46
floor(3.46) = 3
floor(3.46)+1 = 4
i=1 i<=n: true: i*=2
i=2 i<=n: true: i*=2
i=4 i<=n: true: i*=2
i=8 i<=n: true: i*=2
i=16 i<=n: false=> don't loop
```

which is exactly `four`

Comment: Four would be the number of times the loop was executed, the comparison was made five times, right ?

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume some `n` values

For `n=1` loop executes 1 time.
For `n=2` loop executes 2 times.
For `n=3` loop executes 2 times.
For `n=(4 to 7)` loop executes 3 times.
For `n=8` loop executes 4 times.

So for n values like `1,2,4,8,16...` loop executes `1,2,3,4,5...`

Therefore if you compare these values mathematically -

For `n=2^k` loop executes `(k+1)` times from `n=2^k, k=log2n` (logn with base 2)
So loop executes `log2n(floor value)+1` times.

Answer (score -1):

yes code will end you are not initializing `n`. First initialize it then calculte